# How to edit instagram icon on wordpress templates

Tags: wordpress

I am currently building a website for my fishing guide business. You can see it here: https://keystimecharters.com the problem is, at the bottom there are facebook, instagram, twitter and mail icons. I cannot find a way to edit the url link to my instagram account. In the customization layout, when I hover my mouse over the Instagram icon a red circle with a line through it appears.

Maybe this is because I used a template from the wordpress website?

Need a reasoning for this, thanks for your time!

Comment: This should be moved to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Theme Builder it may be inside the builder footer options, if you have a custom template, it maybe on your theme inside footer.php, if your theme has custom options it may be inside the options... What theme are you using? Are you doing this with a builder?